# RoboCopy Entire Folder from Remote 2012R2 Server with UNC path to Local 2016 Folder

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I KNOW this sounds strange but this SIMPLE operation seems to be beyond simple:

```
$SourcePath = '\\remoteserver\driveletter$\path with spaces\folder'
$destpath = localdriverletter:\folder
robocopy $SourcePath $destpath /e
```

...and this fails with...

```
ERROR : No Source Directory Specified.
```

...and YES the path is there...
NOTE: Elevation isn't the issue and the PowerShell is in Admin mode
What I have to do is open explorer and drag-n-drop to ensure the sizes match.

Comment: I would think the second line should look more like this: `$destpath = "${localdriverletter}:\folder"`

Comment: Just realized the `$` in first line is in a weird place, so assuming driveletter is a variable: `$SourcePath = "\\remoteserver\$driveletter\path with spaces\folder"`

Comment: Check this answer for info on using EchoArgs for testing parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71731218/4190564

Answer (score 0):

Why are you obscuring the `driveletter` and `localdriverletter` from us? Now we have no idea if these should represent variables, but if they are, then the error is clear and all has to do with using the wrong (single) quotation marks or even none at all.

Assume you intended something like this:

```
$driveletter       = 'C'
$localdriverletter = 'X'
```

Now construct the paths using double-quotes so the variables get expanded:

```
$SourcePath = "\\remoteserver\$driveletter$\path with spaces\folder"
$destpath   = "${localdriverletter}:\folder"
```

Or use the `-f` [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f):

```
$SourcePath = '\\{0}\{1}$\{2}' -f $remoteserver, $driveletter, 'path with spaces\folder'
$destpath   = '{0}:\folder' -f $localdriverletter
```